# Google Drive sign in fail every time

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to login user on Google and try to upload/download file from Google Drive, this is my activity to login

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;

public class google extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 3:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i("fail", "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, 3);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e("ing", "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i("conn", "API client connected.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i("susp", "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

the only think i get is this [prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ0gu.jpg) to choose account again and again.
this is the error printed in logcat:

```
GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{aa798dc: android.os.BinderProxy@17c2e544}, message=null}
```

i'm sure i'm doing something wrong on activity result or onconnectionfailed, but i can't figure out where and why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following the Google Document about [Connecting and Authorizing the Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api)?

> Authorization for the Google Drive Android API is handled by the `GoogleApiClient`. This is typically created in an activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Drive.API)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.build();
}


After you create the client, you must connect it for authorization to occur.

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Try using this onCreate code and instead of onResume implement it as onStart without include the scopes again just calling the `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`.

The document also provide Error Handlers which can help you verify if your implementation is correct.

> *Note*: The Google Drive Android API currently only supports drive.file and drive.appfolder authorization scopes. If your application requires additional permissions or features not yet available in the Drive Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: i solved the issue, code worked perfectly but i had forgotten to complete the auth survey on google developer console

Answer (score 1):

Could this 3rd party library be helpful? It handles the authentication pretty well and you could even integrate other providers with some lines of code.

```
// CloudStorage cs = new Box(context, "[clientIdentifier]", "[clientSecret]");
// CloudStorage cs = new OneDrive(context, "[clientIdentifier]", "[clientSecret]");
// CloudStorage cs = new GoogleDrive(context, "[clientIdentifier]", "[clientSecret]");
CloudStorage cs = new Dropbox(context, "[clientIdentifier]", "[clientSecret]");
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cs.createFolder("/TestFolder"); // <---
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            stream = assetManager.open("UserData.csv");
            long size = assetManager.openFd("UserData.csv").getLength();
            cs.upload("/TestFolder/Data.csv", stream, size); // <---
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } finally {
            // TODO: close stream
        }
    }
}.start();
```

You can get it from GitHub:
https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-android-sdk

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you. i wish i had found this library long time ago ahahah.. but now my code works